# UnboundLocalError: local variable .. referenced before assignment

Tags: python, scope

I am starting with python. I am trying a very simple class-structure, but i get an error.

This is my script:

```
class controller:

    def initLocal(self):
        path = input('path:')
        local = local()
        local.path = path
        return local


class location:
    pass



class local(location):
    path = None



controller = controller()
local = controller.initLocal()
```

And this is the result i get in the console:

```
path:a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    local = controller.initLocal();    
  File "path\to\test.py", line 5, in initLocal
    local = local();
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'local' referenced before assignment
```

I searched for this error, and found it usually has to do something with uncorrect scopes. I however do not see what i am doing wrong here. Is it 'illegal' to have a class instance with the same name as the class?

If i change the initLocal() method to this:

```
def initLocal(self):
    path = input('path:')
    locale = local()
    locale.path = path
    return locale
```

It works, but i cannot find out why, since controller = controller() does not cause any problems.

Can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong? I have the feeling it might be something really obvious, but i cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to ask: what's up with the semicolons? You don't need them in python.

Comment: You should also capitalize the name of your class as I have a feeling there something odd happening with the bindings.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen You are right. I was just scripting in php, so i added them by accident. Thanks for the correction. Anyway, i deleted them in my script, but the error stays the same.

Comment: @IanAuld Is it required for names of classes in python, or is it just a preference?

Comment: It's part of the style guide but also in this case you are rebinding the name of your class to an instance of that class. How is Python supposed to tell the difference between `controller` the variable and `controller` the class?

Comment: @ianAuld
I see now that = controller without the () also creates an instance. In that case it is obvious that the instance cannot have the same name as the class. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError: local variable 'player' referenced before assignment](//stackoverflow.com/q/17515430/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Location:
    pass

class Local(location):
    path = None

class Controller:
    def initLocal(self):
        path = raw_input('path:')
        local = Local()
        local.path = path
        return local

controller = Controller()
local = controller.initLocal()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For other users, i would like to add the reason why this is necessary: In python a class instance cannot have the same name as a class.

Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: In Python (and I'm sure most other languages) nothing can have the same name as anything else. Once you bind the symbol `foo` to anything and performing an assignment will rebind that symbol. So if you have `class foo` and then later on in your code you do `foo = some_function()` any other time in that scope you try to reference `foo` you will be referencing the result of that function not your class. IT's normal to see `foo = Foo()`, it's important to note that `Foo != foo`